# Clicking an element (not link or button) in Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist

I'm doing an integration test wherein I need to click an html class element and it will go to controller action using Ajax.

Here's my html slim code:

```
table.table-default
 thead
   tr Title
 tbody
   tr.title
     td Hello World
```

The JavaScript handles the `click` event on the `tr`

```
$(function() {
   $('.title').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/admin/dashboards/load_info/
      });
   })
})
```

I raised an error in a controller action to test if it will go to the controller

```
class Admin::DashboardsController < Admin::BaseController
  def load_info
    raise 'hello'.inspect
  end
end
```

When I test on browser it raises `hello`

This is my current setup for testing:

```
gem "minitest-rails"

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda', '~> 3.5'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'minitest-spec-rails'
  gem 'm', '~> 1.5.0'
  gem 'minitest-rails-capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'phantomjs', :require => 'phantomjs/poltergeist'
  gem 'poltergeist'
end
```

My test suit is this:

```
class DashboardFlowTest < Capybara::Rails::TestCase

   before(:all) do 
      Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist
   end

   test "Given I'm at dashboard page when I click the table row it should redirect me to load_info' do 
      visit 'admin/dashboards'

      find('.title').click

      assert_current_path admin_dashboards_load_info_path
   end

end
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError: Request to 'http://127.0.0.1:50102/admin/dashboards/' failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status - Timed out with no open resource requests
```

When I run the test it doesn't raises an error. I'm suspecting that the `click` function on the test only supports link or button or my test is not JavaScript enabled.

Comment: https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails-capybara#specifying-drivers and https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#installation

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Iin my dashboard_flow_test I already tried to add
before(:all) do { Capybara.current_driver = poltergeist }  but I still having an error failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status - Timed out with no open resource requests

Comment: Then add your Capybara config, and everything relevant to this test - for instance where’s the `visit`?

Comment: And document the full error in your question so people don’t have to suggest things you’ve already tried

Comment: I already updated my question @ThomasWalpole

Comment: With that error and assuming this is the first test being run, it’s most likely that your asset compilation is taking longer than the timeout. You can confirm that in your test.log and increase the timeout in your driver registration - https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/blob/master/README.md#customization